# Throttling akka-actor that keeps only the newest messages

Tags: scala, akka, throttling, akka-actor

## Situation

I am using akka actors to update data on my web-client. One of those actors is solely repsonsible for sending updates concerning single `Agent`s. These agents are updated very rapidly (every 10ms). My goal now is to throttle this updating mechanism so that the newest version of every `Agent` is sent every 300ms.

## My code

This is what I came up with so far:

```scala
/**
  * Single agents are updated very rapidly. To limit the burden on the web-frontend, we throttle the messages here.
  */
class BroadcastSingleAgentActor extends Actor {

    private implicit val ec: ExecutionContextExecutor = context.dispatcher
    private var queue = Set[Agent]()

    context.system.scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 300 milliseconds) {
        queue.foreach { a =>
            broadcastAgent(self)(a) // sends the message to all connected clients
        }
        queue = Set()
    }

    override def receive: Receive = {
        // this message is received every 10 ms for every agent present
        case BroadcastAgent(agent) => 
           // only keep the newest version of the agent
           queue = queue.filter(_.id != agent.id) + agent
    }

}
```

## Question

This actor (`BroadcastSingleAgentActor`) works as expected, but I am not 100% sure if this is thread safe (updating the `queue` while potentionally clearing it). Also, this does not feel like I am making the best out of the tools akka provides me with. I found this [article](http://letitcrash.com/post/28901663062/throttling-messages-in-akka-2) (Throttling Messages in Akka 2), but my problem is that I need to keep the newest `Agent` message while dropping any old version of it. Is there an example somewhere similar to what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't thread safe because the scheduling via the `ActorSystem` will happen on another thread than the `receive`. One potential idea is to do the scheduling within the `receive` method because incoming messages to the `BroadcastSingleAgentActor` will be handled sequentially.

```
  override def receive: Receive = {

    case Refresh =>
      context.system.scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 300 milliseconds) {
        queue.foreach { a =>
          broadcastAgent(self)(a) // sends the message to all connected clients
        }
      }
      queue = Set()
    // this message is received every 10 ms for every agent present
    case BroadcastAgent(agent) =>
      // only keep the newest version of the agent
      queue = queue.filter(_.id != agent.id) + agent
  }
```